# CreateDIBSection: Return value vs error

Tags: windows, winapi

[The documentation of CreateDIBSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd183494(v=vs.85).aspx) states:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the newly
>   created DIB, and *ppvBits points to the bitmap bit values.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is NULL, and *ppvBits is NULL.

However, directly after that it states:

> This function can return the following value [...] ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

So, what is meant by this last sentence? I can hardly imagine that it really *returns* that value (possibly it actually calls `SetLastError`). Is this somewhere thoroughly documented?

Comment: look this - http://i.imgur.com/JV3VYcB.png - screenshot from old MSDN (2008) from CreateDIBSection
 article. here all correct

Comment: There is a history of bad MSDN info about GDI function errors.  It of course cannot both return NULL *and* an error code.  Ultimately the info is not useful, GDI functions *always* fail because of invalid parameters.  So if you get NULL then just assume that's what went wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simply an error in the current version of the documentation!

The [`CreateDIBSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183494.aspx) always returns an `HBITMAP`. If the function fails, then it will return 0 (`NULL`), and you can call [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx). `GetLastError` will return `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

This is the standard way that all GDI functions work, not to mention the fact that it is impossible for a function return both `NULL` *and* an error code. I was also able to dig up an old version of the MSDN documentation for this function (circa 2008), and it confirms that the current version of the online documentation is indeed erroneous:

[image]

Comment: I am inclined to believe you, but can you somehow support your claim?

Comment: @phimuemue - try little think by self, not only blindly follow any errors in the documents.

Comment: Maybe I should have written that I already suspected what you claim. However, the entire point of my question is that I would like to find some support for this assumption.

Comment: i have old ofline MSDN 2008 - here screenshot from this function article - http://i.imgur.com/JV3VYcB.png